# Safely free libgit2 objects

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to understand when it is safe to free certain libgit2 objects (I'm writing bindings for a garbage-collected language, and need to keep track of which objects need to keep references to other objects).

The docs for [`git_repository_free`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_free) state:

> Note that after a repository is free'd, all the objects it has spawned will still exist until they are manually closed by the user with `git_object_free`, but accessing any of the attributes of an object without a backing repository will result in undefined behavior

What does "attributes" mean here? It doesn't seem to refer to the "git attributes", i.e. the [`git_attr_*` functions](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/attr), as these are properties of the repository itself, not objects.

1. Does this mean that I should not call any method other than `git_object_free` on any object from that repository?
2. Does this only apply to "git objects" (i.e. tags, commits, trees and blobs)? For example, can I safely use a `git_config` that was obtained via [`git_repository_config`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_config) after calling `git_repository_free`?
3. Are there any other cases that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`git_repository_free` man page](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_free) does not mention "git attributes" (nothing to do with [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for instance)

> ... accessing any of the *attributes* of an object

This is the more generic [OOP term attribute](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing_2009/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Object-oriented_programming_(OOP)#Attributes)

> Attributes
>
> These store information about the object. In the example above we store the `fuel` and `maxSpeed`.
> The attributes are attached to the classes, and if there are several instances (objects) of the classes then each will store its own version of these variables.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408798/safely-free-libgit2-objects/41409775?noredirect=1#comment70025093_41409775) by the [OP Simon Byrne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392585/simon-byrne), libgit2 attributes are not exposed directly. Still if there are [accessor functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Accessor.2C_mutator_and_manager_methods) which return values from those attributes, you would still get bad results if the all repo object was freed.

Accessing an object attribute *after* freeing the memory occupied by that object will lead to unpredictable result.

You should have a valid handle to another Git repo (a "backing repository", a clone of the repository you just freed) in order to access those attributes again.

So:

1. Yes
2. No: that applies only to a git-repository pointer, as shown in [`tests/object/lookup.c`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/89c332e41b12a72d89de40d63bc568c56a2c336a/tests/object/lookup.c#L12-L16). As long as another another does not keep a reference to the `git_repository` that just got freed, that other object is fine. For instance, a `*commit` is just a string: you can still use it (but with another git repo)
3. Not that I can see

Comment: The objects in libgit2 are all opaque, and so don't expose any OOP attributes.

Comment: @SimonByrne Of course. I have edited the answer: if you access/use those attributes through accessor/method on a git repo which was freed, the result will be bad. The point remains: those "attributes" have nothing to do with `.gitattributes`.

Comment: So does that mean the answer to 1 is yes? Any idea about 2 and/or 3?

Comment: How do i know which objects keep a reference to the `git_repository` pointer? e.g does `git_config`?

Comment: @SimonByrne By looking at their structure definition (for instance https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/89c332e41b12a72d89de40d63bc568c56a2c336a/include/git2/types.h)

Comment: @SimonByrne A more complete list: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22struct+git%22&type=Code. I don't see structures depending directly on git_repository itself.

Comment: Cheers, so it's a matter of "the reference is the source" then.

Comment: I've added a PR to hopefully address this: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/4057